# Compile sass at save in Visual Studio Code

Tags: compilation, sass, visual-studio-code

I'm migrating my front end coding from **Visual Studio 2015** to **Visual Studio Code**. I used the **Web Compiler** plug-in at VS2015 so as I saved my ***.scss*** files everything got processed and my changes were automatically reflected at the browser.

Now, same Solution (.NET) and I'm starting to code using VSCode but this is not working out of the box for me. I do know there is a way I can set a *task.json* and afterwards integrate it with gulp.

But I'm just wondering if there is an easier way like the behavior at VS2015.

Why doesn't the build of VSStudio keeps doing this if the .scss gets save as well when working with both editors at the same time?

[I want to save any changes on _*.scss which are imported at the main.scss and get the browser sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3ws4.png)

Comment: there is no out of the box plugin available for VS Code to do the sass compilation. You have to depend on node-sass https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_transpiling-sass-and-less-into-css

Comment: That's the doc I read before posting. I see, so there's no other way.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spook.easysass this might help. I haven't used this.

Comment: there are plugins available... ;) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=sass&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: That's great. I will give a look. Thanks! I can't believe how i missed it.

Comment: I'm using it, but it compiles the .scss you are working on. Do you know how to set its configs?

Comment: sorry. I don't know.